# Поставить временной лимит на итерацию в цикле while (Python)

Tags: python

Мой скрипт выполняет некую работу в цикле `while`. Я бы хотел прервать итерацию и начать заново, в случае превышения временного лимита. Как это можно сделать?

```
while True:
    (work time > 15 sec) -> continue
```

Comment: https://github.com/bitranox/wrapt_timeout_decorator, https://github.com/pnpnpn/timeout-decorator, https://github.com/kata198/func_timeout и т.п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ТРИЛЛЕР**

Давайте поиграем в **киллера** и **жертву**. Пусть наша функция будет жертвой, а тот кто ее убьет будет киллером. Для реализации задуманного воспользуемся процессами, они не блокируют наше приложение и мы можем делать в это время что-то еще.

Код я прокомментировал, надеюсь вопросов не возникнет, но если что спрашивайте.

```
import time
import multiprocessing

TIMEOUT = 6 # время которое есть у жертвы чтобы скрыться
# TIMEOUT = 5 # за это время жертва может быть убита

def function(arg1, arg2):
    time.sleep(5) # тут наша функция жертва что-то делает
    print(f' {arg1} {arg2} ')   # все сделано, она в безопасности за границей

def killer(function):
    # даем жерве задание и возможность скрыться
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=('все', 'хорошо'))
    p.start() 
    time.sleep(TIMEOUT) # киллер ждет определенное время
    if p.is_alive():    # если жертва еще что-то делает
      p.terminate()     # киллер ее убивает  
      print(' жертва убита ')   # и делает фото в качестве доказательтва

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # находим киллера и даем ему функцию жертву которую он уничтожит
    # после TIMEOUT
    
    # это 2 основные строчки для запуска их можно запускать столько раз сколько нужно
    # они не блокируют программу и код ниже может исполняться
    pk = multiprocessing.Process(target=killer, args=([function]))
    pk.start() # отправляем киллера

    # занимаемся повседневными делами
    i = 0  
    while(pk.is_alive()): # пока киллер не убил жертву или не упустил ее
      i += 1
      time.sleep(1)    
      print(i)
```

При TIMEOUT = 5:

```
1
2
3
4
5
 жертва убита 
6
```

При TIMEOUT = 6:

```
1
2
3
4
5
 все хорошо 
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо сделать два цикла и таймер:

```
import time

time_stop = 5

while True:
    t = time.time()
    print("Новый цикл")
    while True:
        if time.time() - t > time_stop:
            print("Время истекло")
            break
```